# Is it possible that external php application can connect google sql

Tags: php, yii

I need to build a php application on well known php framework Yii and I need to connect the application with Google sql. Is this possible. If it is possible then how, can you please help me with any instruction or online tutorial. Please let me know, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JDBC Service of Google Apps Script in order to access Google Cloud SQL. For more information, take a look at [Accessing Google Cloud SQL Databases](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc#accessing_google_cloud_sql_databases). It does not use a native PHP driver, but it's the closest thing you can use with PHP.

Comment: But JDBC connector is a java driver or java classes, so how could I use that from php - any idea would be appreciated. Is there any PHP version of JDBC avaialble or if normal JDBC can be used in PHP then how would that be possible.

Comment: The JDBC connector that is available directly from Cloud SQL is a java driver, but what I proposed is to use Google Apps Script JDBC Connector which is based on javascript. Thus, you can use it from PHP. For more information about Google Apps Script, take a look at [Google Apps Script Overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview).